# Google API for Plus Builder getting failed

Tags: java, google-api

I am trying to get people information from the google API.

Below is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException
{
    plus = new Plus.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
        }
    }).setApplicationName("youtubeSearchSample").build();

    Person profile = plus.people().get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/118359906569721392650?key=<Key>").execute();
    System.out.println("hello-->"+profile.toPrettyString());
}

public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

    // Load client secrets.
    InputStreamReader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader);

    // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
            || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
        System.out.println(
                "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=youtube"
                        + "into src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore}
    FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
    DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);
    System.out.println("scopes-->"+scopes.toString());
    System.out.println("clientSecrets-->"+clientSecrets.toString());
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes).setCredentialDataStore(datastore)
            .build();

    // Build the local server and bind it to port 8080
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();

    // Authorize.
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
}
```

When I try to run the above code I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.<init>(Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/api/client/json/JsonObjectParser;Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/GoogleClientRequestInitializer;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus.<init>(Plus.java:134)
at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus$Builder.build(Plus.java:2086)
at com.google.youtube.search.GoogleUserDetails.main(GoogleUserDetails.java:32)
```

Where as the same I tried for YouTube.Builder it worked fine.

Below is the sample code which I use to for youtube builder.

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, new
HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    }
}).setApplicationName("youtubeSearchSample").build();
```

Here I just replaced the YouTube.Builder with Plus.Builder but I got the above exception which mentioned as above.

Any GoogleAPI experts let me where I made a mistake.

Pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-youtube</artifactId>
        <version>${project.youtube.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Required for any code that makes calls to the Google Analytics API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-youtubeAnalytics</artifactId>
        <version>${project.youtube.analytics.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- This dependency is only used for the Topics API sample, which requires 
        the Jackson JSON parser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>${project.http.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${project.oauth.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Google API dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.googleplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-plus-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev64-1.13.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Usually I get that error, If I have duplicate jars in my class path. Do you ?

Comment: I have added the dependencies used

Comment: are the first two dependencies same ??

Comment: No.its not the same. One is for You tube data and another for you tube data analysis.

Comment: I am still try to figure this out. Anyone knows it

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this error by updating version of api library in pom.xml.

Then you should call

```
mvn clean package
```

Latest versions of google libraries you can find in Maven repository:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.googleplus/google-plus-java-api